# Reduce the repeated lines of IF and else condition code in trigger

Tags: trigger

> I have written the trigger code for excluding Holidays and weekends
>   based on the offset value of the account in salesforce and to populate
>   the deleivery date on the order product object

**Trigger code:**

```
trigger populatedeleiverydate on orderitem(before insert) {
    Map<Id, Order> orders = new Map<Id, Order>();
    Date date1;
    for(OrderItem record: Trigger.new) {
        System.debug('Trigger::'+Trigger.new);
        orders.put(record.OrderId, null);
    }
    orders.putAll([SELECT Account.JDE_Date_Delivery_Offset__c, OrderDeliveryDate__c,Subtype__c FROM Order WHERE Id = :orders.keySet()]);
    Set<String> markets = new Set<String>();
    for(Order record: orders.values()) {
        if(record.Subtype__c == 'Offer') {
            markets.add('FR');
        }
        if(record.Subtype__c == 'ASP') {
            markets.add('IT');
        }

    }

    Map<string, Map<Date,Holiday__c>> holidays = new Map<string, Map<Date,Holiday__c>>();
    for(String market: markets) {
        holidays.put(market, new Map<Date, Holiday__c>());
    }
    for(Holiday__c record: [SELECT Date__c, Country__c FROM Holiday__c WHERE Country__c = :markets]) {
        holidays.get(record.Country__c).put(record.Date__c, record);
    }
    Time midnight = Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0);
    for(OrderItem record: Trigger.new) {
        Order orderRecord = orders.get(record.OrderId);
        if(orderRecord.OrderDeliveryDate__c  == record.Delivery_Date__c)
        {
        String market = orderRecord.SubType__c == 'Offer'? 'FR': 'IT';
        Date tempDate = Date.today()+1;
        DateTime tempDateTime = DateTime.newInstance(tempDate, midnight);
        Integer remainingDays = orderRecord.Account.JDE_Date_Delivery_Offset__c.intValue();
        if(Account.JDE_Date_Delivery_Offset__c==''&& orderRecord.SubType__c == 'Offer')
        {
          remainingDays = 5;
        if(tempDateTime.format('EEEE') == 'Sunday') {
            tempDate = tempDate.addDays(-1);
        }
        while(remainingDays > 0) {
            tempDateTime = DateTime.newInstance(tempDate, midnight);
            if(tempDateTime.format('EEEE') == 'Saturday') {
                tempDate = tempDate.addDays(2);
                 continue;
            }
            if(holidays.get(market) == null || !holidays.get(market).containsKey(tempDate)) {
                remainingDays--;
            }
            tempDate = tempDate.addDays(1);

        }
        }
        if(Account.JDE_Date_Delivery_Offset__c==''&& orderRecord.SubType__c == 'ASP')
         remainingDays = 3;
        if(tempDateTime.format('EEEE') == 'Sunday') {
            tempDate = tempDate.addDays(-1);
        }
        while(remainingDays > 0) {
            tempDateTime = DateTime.newInstance(tempDate, midnight);
            if(tempDateTime.format('EEEE') == 'Saturday') {
                tempDate = tempDate.addDays(2);
                 continue;
            }
            if(holidays.get(market) == null || !holidays.get(market).containsKey(tempDate)) {
                remainingDays--;
            }
            tempDate = tempDate.addDays(1);

        }
        else
        {
        if(tempDateTime.format('EEEE') == 'Sunday') {
            tempDate = tempDate.addDays(-1);
        }
        while(remainingDays > 0) {
            tempDateTime = DateTime.newInstance(tempDate, midnight);
            if(tempDateTime.format('EEEE') == 'Saturday') {
                tempDate = tempDate.addDays(2);
                 continue;
            }
            if(holidays.get(market) == null || !holidays.get(market).containsKey(tempDate)) {
                remainingDays--;
            }
            tempDate = tempDate.addDays(1);

        }
        }

    date1 = orderRecord.OrderDeliveryDate__c;
    if(date1<=tempDate)
    record.Delivery_Date__c = tempDate;
    }
}
```

}

> In this code,I have added some repeated conditions of code, for
>   offsetvalue as Null for asp and Offer, remaining days we have to set
>   the integer value for this process i have repeated this code three
>   times

Like this:

```
if(Account.JDE_Date_Delivery_Offset__c==''&& orderRecord.SubType__c == 'Offer')
        {
          remainingDays = 5;
        if(tempDateTime.format('EEEE') == 'Sunday') {
            tempDate = tempDate.addDays(-1);
        }
        while(remainingDays > 0) {
            tempDateTime = DateTime.newInstance(tempDate, midnight);
            if(tempDateTime.format('EEEE') == 'Saturday') {
                tempDate = tempDate.addDays(2);
                 continue;
            }
            if(holidays.get(market) == null || !holidays.get(market).containsKey(tempDate)) {
                remainingDays--;
            }
            tempDate = tempDate.addDays(1);

        }
        }
        if(Account.JDE_Date_Delivery_Offset__c==''&& orderRecord.SubType__c == 'ASP')
         remainingDays = 3;
        if(tempDateTime.format('EEEE') == 'Sunday') {
            tempDate = tempDate.addDays(-1);
        }
        while(remainingDays > 0) {
            tempDateTime = DateTime.newInstance(tempDate, midnight);
            if(tempDateTime.format('EEEE') == 'Saturday') {
                tempDate = tempDate.addDays(2);
                 continue;
            }
            if(holidays.get(market) == null || !holidays.get(market).containsKey(tempDate)) {
                remainingDays--;
            }
            tempDate = tempDate.addDays(1);

        }
        else
        {
        if(tempDateTime.format('EEEE') == 'Sunday') {
            tempDate = tempDate.addDays(-1);
        }
        while(remainingDays > 0) {
            tempDateTime = DateTime.newInstance(tempDate, midnight);
            if(tempDateTime.format('EEEE') == 'Saturday') {
                tempDate = tempDate.addDays(2);
                 continue;
            }
            if(holidays.get(market) == null || !holidays.get(market).containsKey(tempDate)) {
                remainingDays--;
            }
            tempDate = tempDate.addDays(1);

        }
        }
```

**Is it possible to reduce the lines of same repeated code in trigger,Is there any alternate way is there?**

> Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Where you build the set of market values you have:

```
if(record.Subtype__c == 'Offer') {
    markets.add('FR');
}
if(record.Subtype__c == 'ASP') {
    markets.add('IT');
}
```

But where you lookup you have:

```
String market = orderRecord.SubType__c == 'Offer'? 'FR': 'IT';
```

So if a `record.Subtype__c` of a value other than 'Offer' or 'ASP' would cause an NPE.

One solution is to make the above two pieces of code consistent. An uglier solution would be add a guard:

```
if(holidays.get(market) == null || !holidays.get(market).containsKey(tempDate)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I got the answer:

```
if(Account.JDE_Date_Delivery_Offset__c==''&& orderRecord.SubType__c == 'Offer')
        {
          remainingDays = 5;
        }

        if(Account.JDE_Date_Delivery_Offset__c==''&& orderRecord.SubType__c == 'ASP')
        {
         remainingDays = 3;
        }
```

Thank you